# Languages compiling/interpreting to Javascript (such as Ruby/Python/Coffescript)

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, node.js, opalrb

Newbie self-learner diving into web development here.  My goal is to learn how to build web-apps.  Three quick questions:

1. Ruby and Python seem to have offshoots that compile their respective code to Javascript (i.e. Opal/Pyjamas).  If I can get an understanding of the DOM, i.e. the DOM, do I have to even learn the full language of Javascript or can I just rely on Ruby/Python compiling to JS?
2. Everyone seems to be talking about node.js allowing for javascript on both the browser and server.  Does that mean that if I know Javascript and use Node, I don't need python or ruby for web dev?
3. If node.js allows for server/client side javascript, couldn't someone just learn something like Coffeescript or Typescript and throw python, ruby or php aside?

Comment: Please clarify your first question. When you say, "do I have to even learn the full language?", which language do you mean? Ruby/Python/Javascript? What is the difference between "[getting] an understanding of how Javascript does what it does" and "[learning] the full language"? I'm interpreting the question as, "do I have to learn the full language [in order to accomplish my goal]?". What is your goal? If you don't have one, you don't need to learn anything :-)

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I've updated my question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You shouldn't even need to understand the syntax of Javascript. Just an understanding of the DOM should suffice. Having said that, all the DOM examples will be in JS syntax, so reading them will be tricky. Being able to debug the transpiled javascript is also usefulo
2. Correct. You can write a server an client with javascript in all the places
3. Also correct. This is probably a better option, as these languages map more closely to the underlying javascript.

Comment: Thanks Eric! I appreciate the guidance.